# Multiple SVG Components not working or render as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, next.js, frontend

I'm having a strange problem; and haven't been able to get a solution for it.

Context:
NextJS App. I have 5 different svgs, and created some Icon components with them:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as NoReactionSvg } from './img/no-reaction.svg';
import { ReactComponent as OkSvg } from './img/ok.svg';
import { ReactComponent as QuestionSvg } from './img/question.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ToolSvg } from './img/tool.svg';
import { ReactComponent as TrophySvg } from './img/trophy.svg';

const Icon = ({ size = 'medium', color = 'currentColor', style, children, ...props }) => {
  const sizes = {
    small: '16px',
    medium: '24px',
    large: '32px',
  };

  return React.cloneElement(children, {
    width: sizes[size],
    height: sizes[size],
    color,
    style,
    ...props,
  });
};

export const NoReactionIcon = (props) => (
  <Icon {...props}>
    <NoReactionSvg />
  </Icon>
);

export const OkIcon = (props) => (
  <Icon {...props}>
    <OkSvg />
  </Icon>
);

export const QuestionIcon = (props) => (
  <Icon {...props}>
    <QuestionSvg />
  </Icon>
);

export const ToolIcon = (props) => (
  <Icon {...props}>
    <ToolSvg />
  </Icon>
);

export const TrophyIcon = (props) => (
  <Icon {...props}>
    <TrophySvg />
  </Icon>
);
```

And I'm trying to use these components like this:

```js
<div><TrophyIcon /></div>
<div><ToolIcon /></div>
<div><QuestionIcon /></div>
<div><NoReactionIcon /></div>
<div><OkIcon /></div>
```

Problem is, it's not working as expected. As you can see, I have 5 components; but it's only rendering the first 3 (the other 2 are omitted).

[image]

Now, if I move the 4th icon to the top, suddenly it renders! But still the last one is not being rendered.

[image]

And If I move it to the top, suddenly the 2nd icon is not being rendered anymore.

[image]

I'm totally clueless about what's going on with this. Maybe is it a configuration on nextjs? Or maybe I'm creating these svg components wrong?

Comment: The first thing to check is that all the icons have unique ids and classes i.e. there's not two elements with the same id value in two different icons, nor are there duplicate class names.

Comment: return React.cloneElement(children, {
    ...props,
     id:`"icon" + someUniqueNumber` // try this add an uniqueid into the clone element
  });

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem issue for more than a day, the solution to this problem is in your SVGComponents you should be using id='some-value' and for other SVGComponents you would be using the same value, you will need to make each SVG with unique ids,. eg

```
export default function AEIcon() {
return (
    <svg
        width="20"
        height="20"
        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >
        <rect width="20" height="20" fill="url(#pattern0)" />
        <defs>
            <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
                <use xlinkHref="#image0_698_26468123" transform="scale(0.0125)" />
            </pattern>
            <image
                id="image0_698_26468123"
                width="80"
                height="80"
                xlinkHref="data:image/png;base64,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" 
            />
        </defs>
    </svg>
);
```

}

in the above component id is used 2 places and their reference is also used, id should match with the respective references and the ids should not be same in any other SVGComponent.

in my case I was using similar svgs but all of them had same IDs.